# Existence Of Electric Field Lines

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, electric-fields, vector-fields

Can an Electric Field  with field lines Like So Exist:

http://puu.sh/tWkJ

One Of my friends said it couldn't as the field lines here are not conservative ; so it cannot exist ; Is he right?

Or can it be made to exist

Comment: Dont the Electric Field Lines mean the same thing?

Comment: Yep.  "Lines" is missing in your question.  EDIT: I see, you have it in title, but you dont have it in the text.  Never mind.

Comment: "Existence Of Electric Field Lines" & "as the field lines here" Ive used the word like twice...so.....okay im editing it.

Comment: OK, fine, I somehow missed title reading text :)

Comment: The link to this image is broken. Please replace it with an image hosted at the standard StackExchange image hosting service by using the image upload button on the question editing window. Or does anyone remember what that picture was?

Comment: Voting to close as irreparably damaged by link rot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yes,* your friend is right. Within electrostatics, an electric field $\vec{E}$ should be curl-free $\vec{\nabla} \times\vec{E}= \vec{0}$. The drawn electric [field lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line) looks like the electric field is of the form

$$ E_x=E_x(y), \qquad E_y=0, \qquad E_z=0, $$

cf. the [rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line) that to depict the magnitude $|\vec{E}|$, a selection of field lines is drawn such that the density of field lines (number of field lines per unit perpendicular area) at any location is proportional to $|\vec{E}|$ at that point. Here the $x$-axis is horizontal, the $y$-axis is vertical, and the $z$-axis perpendicular to the plane.

This is only curl-free if $E_x=E_x(y)$ is independent of $y$, which it isn't on the figure.

Comment: Can we Make Something that generates a field like so 'coz I've Heard that induced electric field is non conservative

Comment: He didn't say the electric field was conservative

Comment: @The-Ever-Kid: Perhaps you are referring to [Faraday's induction law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction). With the help of an appropriate time-varying magnetic field, the electric field lines in the figure may be realized.

Comment: @Physiks lover: Well, indirectly. OP tagged it as electrostatics, which traditionally implies a curlfree electric field.

Comment: +1, although technically if there is nontrivial $z$-dependence, this _could_ be a slice of a zero-curl configuration. (Admittedly one is not given any reason to believe that is the case.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Could You Elaborate "if there is nontrivial z-dependence, this could be a slice of a zero-curl configuration"